# Cannot convert value of type 'testViewController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, presentviewcontroller

I receive this error with the following code.  I have a View Controller class called "testViewController".  I'm trying to press a button and make it appear, but this error is showing in my code.  Help!

```
self.present(testViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I expect this should show the new view controller but it does not.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: You wrote *I have a View Controller class called "testViewController"* so you are passing the *type* as parameter rather than an instance.  If you would conform to the naming convention that class names start with a capital letter you could see the error at once.

Comment: Can you also post the definition of your `testViewController` class?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by the "definition" of the class.  Apologies but I'm fairly new to this so I get caught up on the terminology.  It is literally a new view controller with one label on it that says "Hi".  Just trying to nail down how to make it appear at the press of a button as none of the posted code in stack OF seem to work without error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an instance not

```
let vc1 = TestViewController.self // wrong
let vc2 = TestViewController() // right

self.present(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil) // right
self.present(TestViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) // wrong
self.present(vc1, animated: true, completion: nil) // wrong
```

---

**Edit:** If the vc is inside storyboard load it like

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCID") as! TestViewController
self.present(vc1, animated: true, completion: nil) // right
```

Comment: i did this, and it simply does not move to the new view controller, but no errors are present.

Comment: do you create `TestViewController` in storyboard ?

Comment: i did create TestViewController, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I just found code that works.  Thanks all. Here it is:

```swift
let testViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyTest") as! testViewController // I created MyTest in the identifier field of the identity inspector.

self.present(testViewController, animated: true)
```